# Logback fire mail for warnings

Tags: smtp, logback

I want to configure Logback to fire an email whenever any warnings are found on server.

Right now it is already configure for `error` level we are getting mails when any error occurred. However same code with changing root level to `warn` doesn't work.

All sender, receiver, host etc. details are same for which use in error SMTP appender so it's not a server issue. Below is my code.

```
<appender name="EMAILWARN" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <smtpHost>XXXX</smtpHost>
    <to>XXXX</to>
    <!-- additional destinations are possible -->
    <from>XXXX</from>

    <!--
    <discriminator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator">
        <key>req.remoteHost</key> visit http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html#mis for different key values
        <defaultValue>default</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    -->

    <!-- <subject>RCM-Error: ${HOSTNAME} %X{req.remoteHost} %logger - %m</subject> -->
    <subject>Error: ${HOSTNAME} - %m %logger</subject>

    <!-- <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout"> -->
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
        <pattern>%date%X{REMOTE_ADDR}%X{USER_NAME}%level%logger%message</pattern>
    </layout>

    <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTrackerImpl">
        <bufferSize>20</bufferSize> <!-- set number of log entry to send per email -->
    </cyclicBufferTracker>
</appender>

<root level="warning">
    <appender-ref ref="EMAILWARN" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender` use an e[valuator to trigger the email send procedure](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#smtpAppender_Evaluator). The default one triggers at ERROR level.

So what you need is an evaluator that tiggers at WARN level (and above)

```
<appender ... class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    ...
    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
        <expression>return level >= WARN;</expression>
    </evaluator>
    ...
</appender>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Please note you need to add "org.codehaus.janino/janino" as the extra dependency

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that **warning** is not a valid logback level.

Try changing your root logger level to *warn*:

```
  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="EMAILWARN" />
  </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters as below, which will select log levels error and warn

```
<appender name="EMAILWARN" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
   <!-- rest of your configurations -->
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
  </filter>
</appender>
```